# How to import .mobileconfig files without MDM Server?

Tags: macos, mac, monterey

We do not have any external MDM tied to our Mac devices. We use CrowdStrike as antivirus which requires "Full Disk Access" and "Web Preferences" Extensions Enabled. These are granted while we install CrowdStrike manually.

We are trying to import the official CrowdStrike profile in our Mac M1 and later laptops with their OS being macOS Ventura 13.x , as detailed in https://supportportal.crowdstrike.com/s/article/ka16T000000wtMWQAY

The command that we are using to import is :

```
open /System/Library/PreferencePanes/Profiles.prefPane ~/Desktop/MAC/Official-CS-Falcon-Profile-no-Kext.mobileconfig
```

- This opens up the Profiles utility, where user can accept the prompts and install the profile.
- This profile is not signed (meaning its unsigned)

However this fails with error:

> Profile installation failed
>
> The profile must originate from a user-approved MDM server

I have also tried to install the profile with self-signed certificate, but the error is same

Is there a way to install / import a profile without an MDM Server ?

Please guide me

Comment: Unfortunately, the link requires a login